# What's a a good way to stop a pool of threads from running?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, threadpool, exit

I've been working on a project lately, and i need to manage a pair of thread pools.
What the worker threads in the pools do is basically execute some kind of pop operation to each respective queue, eventually wait on a condition variable (`pthread_cond_t`) if there is no available value in the queue, and once they get an item, parse it and execute operations accordingly.
What i'm concerned about is the fact that i want to have no memory leaks, and to achieve that i noticed that calling a `pthread_cancel` on each thread when the main process is exiting is definitely a bad idea, as it leaves a lot of garbage around.
The point is, my first thought was to use a exit flag which i can set when the threads need to exit, so that they can easily free memory and call a `pthread_exit`...
I guess i should set this flag, then send a broadcast signal to the threads waiting on the condition variable and check the flag right after the pop operation...

Is this really the correct way to implement a good thread pool termination? I don't feel that much confident about this... 
I'm writing some pseudo-code here to explain what i'm talking about

Each pool thread will run some code structured like this:

```
/* Worker thread (which will run on each pool thread) */
{ /* Thread initialization */ ... }
loop {
   value = pop();
   { /* Mutex lock because of the shared flag */ ... }
   if (flag) {{ /* Free memory and unlock mutex */ ... } pthread_exit(); }
   { /* Unlock the mutex */ ... }
   { /* Elaborate value */ ... }
}
return NULL;
```

And there will be some kind of `pool_stopRunning()` function which will look like:

```
/* pool_stopRunning() function code */
{ /* Acquire flag mutex */ ... }
setFlag(flag);
{ /* Unlock flag mutex */ ... }
{ /* Acquire queue mutex */ ... }
pthread_cond_broadcast(...);
{ /* Unlock queue mutex */ ... }
```

Thanks in advance, i just need to be sure that there isn't a fancy-er way to stop a thread pool... (or get to know a better way, by any chance)
As always, i'm sorry if there is any typo, i'm not and english speaker and it's kind of late right now >:

Comment: It's necessary to use mutexes to protect the flag.  But try to minimise time the mutexes are held.   For example, in the thread, copy the flag value, and release the mutex, and then exit if the copied flag value says so.   No matter what you do though, clean termination of threads requires cooperation between the main thread and other threads if there is any shared state involved.

Comment: I would probably look into this https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool/blob/master/thpool.c, look inside the destroy function to get an idea of how this lib implements it.

Comment: First, do you need to do this?  If you are only deleting the pool at process termination then, on mainstream multitasking OS like Linux/Windows, you don't need to signal/stop/terminate anything unless there is an overriding need to do so.  The OS is much better at stopping threads than user code is, (user code cannot stop threads runing on another core than the thread requesting the stop).  I suspect premature stoptimization...

Comment: @ThingyWotsit well i can't have any memory leak, and leaving threads running is a huge "no" for those

Comment: @NokiStrawby all non-trivial OS will safely and securely terminate ALL your threads, (even if they are running in a tight loop on another core), when you request process termination.  When all the threads are stopped, it will deallocate other resources like process memory.  There will be no leak.  Your problem only arises when you need to destroy a thread pool during the app run. That would be unusual since thread pools are usually around for the whole app lifetime, (that being somewhat the point:).

Comment: @ThingyWotsit the threads will indeed stop, but you will still have memory leaks just like you would if you don't free memory on a single threaded program

Comment: At process termination, it makes no difference whether the process hosts one thread or 100.  All the threads are stopped and then all process memory, and other resources allocated to the process, freed.  There will be no memory leaks: the OS reclaims it all, (mod. any such resources explicitly shared with other processes, where the shared resource reference count is decremented).  If an OS leaks memory when terminating a process, (no matter how many threads), then it is fatally flawed.  Windows, Linux and the like do not leak - it would be noticed:)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit that's not what valgrind would say.
I mean, ofc memory is reclaimed, but it is a horrible practice not freeing pointers in C, and as i am developing a uni project, i have to make sure there is no such thing (besides that, one preliminary test which determines whether the project is discarded or not, without even reading the code, is running it in valgrind and checking if there are 0 errors, which includes having no memory leaks)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing will work, but I would suggest a different approach...

You already have a mechanism for assigning tasks to threads, complete with all appropriate synchronization. So instead of complicating the design with some new parallel mechanism, just define a new type of task called "STOP". If there are `N` threads servicing a queue and you want to terminate them, push `N` STOP tasks onto the queue. Then just wait for all of the threads to terminate. (This last can be done via "join", so it should not require any new mechanism, either.)

No muss, no fuss.

Comment: There is not even any need to post n 'poison-pills'.  When the thread recognizes the suicide-request, it can push it back onto the queue before exiting/terminating.  This will teminate any number of threads with one task:)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i haven't thought of that.
The fact is that i want the threads to terminate as soon as i send the stop signal, without completing the remaining tasks...
Gues that's a minor problem tho, as i could implement it by pop-ping all previous requests from the queue and then pushing the stop tasks

Comment: ..and, if the queued items are pointers, you could use a NULL pointer as the poison-pill, so eliminating the need to delete the killer task when it's done its work.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to symmetry with setting the flag and reducing serialization, this code:

```
{ /* Mutex lock because of the shared flag */ ... }
if (flag) {{ /* Free memory and unlock mutex */ ... } pthread_exit(); }
{ /* Unlock the mutex */ ... }
```

should look like this:

```
{ /* Mutex lock because of the shared flag */ ... }
flagcopy = readFlag();
{ /* Unlock the mutex */ ... }
if (flagcopy) {{ /* Free memory ... } pthread_exit(); }
```

Having said that, you can (should?) factor the mutex code into the setFlag and readFlag methods.

There is one more thing. If the flag is only a boolean and it is only changed once before the whole thing shuts down (i.e., it's never unset after being set), then I would argue that protecting the read with a mutex is not required.

I say this because if the above assumptions are true and if the loop's duration is *very* short and the loop iteration frequency is high, then you would be imposing undue serialization upon the business task and potentially increasing the response time unacceptably.

Comment: That's interesting, but thinking on it, i am a little afraid of not checking the mutex before reading the flag, the fact is that as far as i remember, setting any common variable isn't an atomic operation (or was there that sig_atomic_t type which was ?), and just because this is an uni project, i guess i should implement it the thing keeping in mind that even though it's practically impossible to bug the code out by doing that, the code will be evaluated judging the fact that theoretically there could be some race condition

Comment: thinking more about that, the worst case scenario would be a worker thread looping one time more than it should, not a big deal anyway